# error in importing css class to react component

Tags: css, reactjs

I want a card with a yellow background. Not able to get it from 1st code but 2nd working properly.
What is wrong with the first code?

```
import styles from "/home/jatin/maylast/project1/src/index.css";
function Todo() {
  return (
    <div className={styles.card}>
      <h2>Title</h2>
      <div>
        <button>Delete</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

```
function Todo() {
  return (
    <div className='card'>
      <h2>Title</h2>
      <div>
        <button>Delete</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try passing `styles.card` like this :

```
import styles from "/home/jatin/maylast/project1/src/index.css";

function Todo() {
  return (
    <div style={styles.card}>
      <h2>Title</h2>
      <div>
        <button>Delete</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Don't forget that the style object must be in "Object" syntax and not in css syntax
See here : https://codesandbox.io/s/react-playground-forked-g87i4q?file=/index.js

Comment: In the index.css file I have defined 'card' as a class, not as an object that's why I am using className instead of style.<br/>                                                                                                                                      ```.card {
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  width: 40%;
  border-color: #000000;
  background-color:yellow;
}```

Comment: In this way you must import the class `card` by `className` in your component.
Remember if you wanted to make your first code work you need to do the same way of my codepen example (in object syntax) otherwise is pure css so by`className`